# onShippingChange does not work with data.shipping_address.country_code

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to set it so that it will reject all shipping addresses apart from the UK. My code is the following;

```
onShippingChange: function(data, actions){
    if(data.shipping_address.country_code!=="GB"){
        return actions.reject();
    }
    return actions.resolve();
},
```

But it does not work. I don't receive any errors.

I have also tried changing it to the following which also does not work;

```
return actions.reject(new Error("We do not support your country."));
```

The only way I can get it to *slightly* work is if I use an alert and throw a new error instead of using reject(), for example;

```
onShippingChange: function(data, actions){
    if(data.shipping_address.country_code!=="GB"){
        alert("We do not support your country.");
        throw new Error();
    }
},
```

But doing it this way does not close the PayPal popup/modal.

Answer (score 0):

try to have the `return actions.resolve();` in else statment, i might be called regardless of `return actions.reject();`

```
onShippingChange: function(data, actions){
        if(data.shipping_address.country_code!=="GB"){
            return actions.reject();
        } else {
        return actions.resolve();
        }
},
```